# C code to print the pattern 1 22 22 333 333 333

Tags: c

I want to write code in C to generate the pattern:

```
1
22
22
333
333
333
```

..and I need help. Thank you! :)

This is what I've tried:

```
int n,i,j;
scanf("%d",&n);

for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    printf("\n");
    for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
    {
        printf("%d",i);
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you try your code? Do you see what's missing?

Comment: `int n,i,j,k; for(i=j=k=0,scanf("%d",&n);++k<i||(k=0,i&&puts(""),++j<i||(j=0,++i<=n));printf("%d",i));` *scnr* (on a serious note, use some **spaces** and declare variables one per line, makes the code readable :))

Comment: Why are you guys doing the OP's homework?

Comment: @alk I don't think he wants to turn in the code from my comment although this would work ;)

Comment: Agreed, but still ... ;-) @FelixPalmen

Comment: This question needs a proper [mcve], including the actual output...

Comment: @alk Because op OP seems to have tried seriously to solve the problem him/herself.

Comment: Yes, that's why I think *helping* is fine, but to be helpful for a homework assignment, OP needs to understand where the error was. I'd say an answer should explain that, a helpful comment should push into the correct direction.

Comment: We would help OPs best by helping them formulate proper questions with proper [mcve]s

Comment: Oh, I'm the OP...  what does that mean?

Comment: That means good questions should always include a well formed question, what the expected output/result should be and code to show what you tried. You did all of those things. There's more good info in the link @AnttiHaapala provided as well. That being said, will your question help future readers? Probably not because it's a very specific use case so that's probably why it got some down votes. You were darn close and I think if you would have walked through your code the answer would have come to you!

Comment: Yes, probably you are right, I should have tried a little harder..and I'm new here and to be honest I don't know when to use downvotes for example or how to ask a question 'properly' soooo don't be so strict with me guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the original question is pretty close - you just needed one more loop inside to iterate and print the numbers X times.

If you want your output to look like

```
1
22
22
333
333
333
```

then this will do it

```
int main()
{
    int n,i,j,k;
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
        {
            for(k=1;k<=i;k++) { //this prints the numbers X times
                printf("%d",i);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```